# How to detect color of text on the command line through a script?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, console

I have a command-line program that outputs some text in different colors depending on the status.
The text doesnt change on multiple calls, but its color changes.

Eg:The program outputs the text "S14789" on the console.
The color of this text will be in red if the status is fail, and green if pass

I need to write a script to do some thing else depending on the color (status). Any suggestions?

Comment: Tried anything up to now ?

Comment: Is the script return only one value for one run or it continuously returns the text in different colours ?

Comment: Pipe it into cat -v and look what the escape sequence is, there are many ways to colour text on linux

Comment: @SriharshaKalluru: The script returns one value for one run.

Comment: @Jidder: Yes, I can see a few escape sequences. i will try to do something with that. Thanks.
The output I got was: ^[[0m^[[32;40mS14789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is what I did to perform tasks depending on color output:

`/usr/bin/smoke` is my program which outputs text in a particular color. Search for the color escape sequence and perform tasks (Thanks to @Jidder for suggesting `cat -v`).

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNT=`/usr/bin/smoke | cat -v | fgrep "^[[32" | wc -l`
if [ $COUNT -gt 0 ] 
then
    #Color found, do something
else
    #Color not found, do something else
fi
```

Note: 32 is for green. For other colors refer the list of escape sequences: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes#general_useful_ascii_codes

Answer (score 0):

As the scripts are giving one value at one time you can modify the script to change the exit values to 0 if it is pass and 1 if it is pass.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Print in green"
exit 0

$ ./script1.sh
Print in green
$ echo $?
0
```

The same way you can use `exit 1` which return a value `1` to `?` variable and you can use it to determine whether the script pass or fail.

Comment: I have no control over the script (its actually an ELF binary) which returns the value I need to check. I need to use its output and write a script to do some other things depending on the output

Comment: In that case get the output the command and pass it to cat command. `<your command> |cat -v`